# Temporarily unset bash option -x

Tags: bash, echo, debugging, output

I like to use `set -x` in scripts to show what's going on, especially if the script is going to run in a CI/CD pipeline and I might need to debug some failure post-hoc.

One annoyance with doing this is that if I want to echo some text to the user (e.g., a status message or `"I'm starting to do $X"`) then that message gets output twice - once for the `echo` command itself being echoed, and then once as the output of that `echo` command.

What's a good way to make this nicer?  One solution is this:

```
set -x

... bunch of normal commands that get echoed

(
  # Temporarily don't echo, so we don't double-echo
  set +x
  echo "Here is my status message"
)

... rest of commands get echoed again
```

But the two problems with that are

1. That's a lot of machinery to write every time I want to tell the user something, and it's "non-obvious" enough that it probably requires the comment every time
2. It echoes the `set +x` too, which is undesirable.

Is there another option that works well?

Something like [Make's feature of prepending an `@` to suppress echoing](http://www.sis.pitt.edu/mbsclass/tutorial/advanced/makefile/build.htm#:%7E:text=The%20%40%20symbol%20is%20commonly%20seen,the%20amount%20of%20typing%20required.) would be great, but I've not been able to find such a feature in Bash.

Comment: 1. you can convert it into a function but of course it won't help with 2)

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Converting it to a function doesn't even help with 1., because you have to call that function with the message as an argument, and that will be echoed.

Comment: It helps with 1 because you don't have to disable tracing explicitly before each log

Comment: Don't use Bash then.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk The point of disabling tracing was to not get the message printed twice. Using a function is as useful as using echo directly.

Comment: Similar: [bash: escape individual lines from \`-x\` echoing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/60041)

Comment: `set -x` is a debugging tool, not something intended to build nice text interfaces.

Comment: @chepner if there's a better technique to show the user what's happening as it's happening, I'm interested to hear it.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to bend the mechanics of `set -x` just because you don't want your `echo`s printed twice.

Comment: Choose the right tool for the job, if bash doesn't work for you, choose a different language. Nowadays there are not a lot of excuses left for not doing that.

Comment: Bash is fine for simple scripts, as soon as it gets complex, it's better to use a higher level language. I don't (seriously) get why so many people insist on doing everything in bash - it's stupid.

Comment: I think in many cases, complex Bash scripts started out simple and took on more and more features until they became complex. I've got one bash monstrosity that's thousands of lines of code split over two dozen or so files, but started out as just a couple dozen lines. Nobody's got time to rewrite the thing as long as it keeps working; I've been using it for five years, and it's more reliable than some of the fancy-shmancy things our tooling team has thrown at us.

Comment: @AndrewRay Well that's very unfortunate. The person in charge should've made the switch to a higher language when it was still manageable. I don't mean to judge, it's a fast moving world and sometimes, we just want to get stuff done in the moment. However, I don't think it's right to support questionable questions (heh) like this one. The positive (it seems) reception only validates the idea of "let's just keep using bash and use some hack to get around X". Personally, I think the most upvoted answer here really is an abomination. There's an idiom "XY Problem", why not apply it here?

Comment: There is too much discussion and opinionating in these comments, please move to chat if you would like to continue.  I'm quite happy with the answer I accepted - when asking the question I was doubtful that any such solution was even possible.  Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a horrible kluge, and I feel dirty for suggesting it, but... you could do this with a [magic alias](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/aliases.html). The key to this trick is that aliases are expanded as part of the parsing phase of command execution, so `set -x` won't make anything print as they expand (unlike a function). So you can make an alias that prepends the "turn off `-x`" boilerplate before the `echo` command, and then it turns out you also need a function to run the "turn `-x` back on" boilerplate at the end.

You also need to turn on alias expansion in your script. It's normally disabled, so that e.g. if you have something like `grep` aliased to `grep --color`, that won't make color codes get randomly injected up whenever the script uses `grep`. So it's safest to run `unalias -a` first, to remove any potentially troublesome aliases.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
unalias -a
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias cleanecho='{ set +x; } 2>/dev/null; resetx_after echo'
resetx_after() { "$@"; set -x; }

set -x
cleanecho "Ha, ha, you can't see the command that printed this!"
```

How it works: a command like `cleanecho "something"` expands to:

```
{ set +x; } 2>/dev/null; resetx_after echo "something"
```

`{ set +x; } 2>/dev/null` turns off `-x` mode (with its own trace redirected to /dev/null). Then `resetx_after echo "something"` runs, executing:

```
{ echo "something"; set -x; }
```

...which prints the string and then turns `-x` tracing back on.

BTW, if you want to be able to use other commands like `printf` similarly, you could add similar aliases for them:

```
alias cleanprintf='{ set +x; } 2>/dev/null; resetx_after printf'
```

...or just make a generic don't-trace-this alias to use as a prefix:

```
alias notrace='{ set +x; } 2>/dev/null; resetx_after'
notrace printf 'set -x disabled for this command\n'
```

Comment: oooh nice, I'm going to have to meditate on whether to add this to our setup scripts...

Answer (score 14):

You can achieve this in Bash by *not* using `set -x` and instead trapping `DEBUG` and doing your own tracing:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -T

trap '! [[ "$BASH_COMMAND" =~ ^(echo|printf) ]] &&
      printf "+ %s\n" "$BASH_COMMAND"' DEBUG

foo=bar
echo This is a test
echo $foo
[[ $foo = bar ]] && /usr/bin/printf 'Matched\n'
```

The idea is to add commands you want to ignore to the regex in the `trap` line. Running the above produces

```
+ foo=bar
This is a test
bar
+ [[ $foo = bar ]]
+ /usr/bin/printf 'Matched\n'
Matched
```

`set -T` ensures that the trap is inherited by shell functions.

You can add a separate mechanism to enable and disable the trap, *e.g.* with a shell variable:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -T

status() {
        NOTRACE=1 echo "$@"
}

trap '! [[ "$BASH_COMMAND" =~ ^(status|NOTRACE=) ]] &&
      printf "+ %s\n" "$BASH_COMMAND"' DEBUG

foo=bar
test=$(echo baz)
echo This is a test
status This is a status report
echo $foo
[[ $foo = bar ]] && /usr/bin/printf 'Matched\n'
```

This produces

```
+ foo=bar
+ test=$(echo baz)
+ echo This is a test
This is a test
This is a status report
+ echo $foo
bar
+ [[ $foo = bar ]]
+ /usr/bin/printf 'Matched\n'
Matched
```

Comment: Interesting idea.  The problem I'm seeing, though, is that this would affect every `echo`, including `echo foo > file.txt`, so I'd want to have a special command like `status` for non-echoing output - but then the echo inside *that* command gets echoed...

Comment: See the update, all this can easily be dealt with by changing the expression used to disable echoing.

Answer (score -2):

Easy. And you already half way solved it: just move `set -x` into the block

```
#!/bin/sh
echo a
(
    set -x
    echo b
)
echo c
```

```
$ a.sh
a
+ echo b
b
c
```

If you want to not trace a part of the script - do the tracing in two parts

```
#!/bin/sh
echo a
(
    set -x
    echo b
)
echo c
(
    set -x
    echo d
)
echo e
```

Just trace the suspicious pieces instead of whole script.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, this seems to be the opposite of what I'm asking.

Comment: @KenWilliams, though they're right in that if you don't want the `set +x` visible in the execution trace, you need some way to do it implicitly. Any method of running (the equivalent of) `set +x` would show in the trace, as would e.g. any variable assignment that modifies the trace output itself.

Comment: @KenWilliams You want to *not* trace a piece of script? Then trace everything else, safe for that piece. Do not turn the tracing on for the whole script. I updated the answer to show it.

Comment: This requires that the traced parts of the script run in subshells, meaning that they can't do things like set variables that'll survive past the end of a traced section. It also can't handle having an untraced part in the middle of a complex command (e.g. inside a loop or`if` or `case` or...).